# Using a break statement to exit a loop

Tags: python

i want to detect when the program sees the value 26, i have a function that looks like this

```
val = 26
for n in range (0,101):
    if n in val:
        print(n,"is the value i am looking for")
        break
    else:
        print(n)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

What is wrong with this function

Comment: You can't do `if n in val` as `val` is not any type of iterator object like list or set or dict - it is an integer

Comment: `if n in val:` will attempt to check if `n` is in 26, which doesn't make any sense because `type 'int' (26) is not iterable`

Comment: Try `if n == val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n in val` checks whether the value `n` is in the iterable `val`. The correct check here is `n == val`